# What is the difference between Orbit Gum and Orbit for Kids

Tags: sugar-free

If this is not the right forum for this question, please let me know where to post it.

Comment: We answer questions about food in the context of cooking, not just arbitrary questions about food - things like restaurants and already-made food are indeed outside the scope of our site. I don't think there's a stackexchange site that covers this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any reason to say it can't be asked here. Orbit for Kids is available in "kid friendly" flavors (Bubble Gum and Strawberry Banana). I see nothing at all different in the formulation beyond the flavor. For the most part it is a marketing gimmick. The "for kids" flavors have xylitol as the second ingredient. The adult flavors have it as a 3rd or 4th ingredient. That probably just means that the kid's version is somewhat sweeter.

Comment: The reason, FYI, is the same reason we don't take questions like "what can a vegan eat at McDonald's?", "how do I grow potatoes?", or "which side of the plate does the fork go on?" - we're just about cooking, not everything to do with food.